# Running `connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec` using kubernetes client corev1api gives bad request

Tags: python, api, kubernetes

kubernetes client corev1api connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec fails to run for python.

I have checked the python version == 2.7 and pip freeze - ipaddress==1.0.22, urllib3==1.24.1 and websocket-client==0.54.0 are the versions which satisfy the requirement - as mentioned here: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/README.md#hostname-doesnt-match
followed the issue on this thread - https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/36 - not much help.

Tried usings stream as suggested here - https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/exec.py

Ran:

```
api_response = stream(core_v1_api.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec,
                      name, namespace,
                      command=exec_command,
                      stderr=True, stdin=False,
                      stdout=True, tty=False)
```

Got this error:

> ApiException: (0)
>   Reason: hostname '10.47.7.95' doesn't match either of '', 'cluster.local'

Without stream using directly the CoreV1Api -

Ran :

```
core_v1_api = client.CoreV1Api()
api_response = core_v1_api.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec(name=name,namespace=namespace,command=exec_command,stderr=True, stdin=False,stdout=True, tty=False)
```

Got this error:

> ApiException: (400)
>   Reason: Bad Request
>   HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Sat, 05 Jan 2019 08:01:22 GMT', 'Content-Length': '139', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
>   HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Upgrade request required","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote a simple program to check that:

```
from kubernetes import client, config
from kubernetes.stream import stream

# create an instance of the API class

config.load_kube_config()
api_instance = client.CoreV1Api()

exec_command = [
    '/bin/sh',
    '-c',
    'echo This is Prafull Ladha and it is test function']
resp = stream(api_instance.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec, "nginx-deployment-76bf4969df-467z2", 'default',
              command=exec_command,
              stderr=True, stdin=False,
              stdout=True, tty=False)
print("Response: " + resp)
```

It is working perfectly fine for me.

I believe you're using `minikube` for development purpose. It is not able to recognise your hostname. You can make it work by disabling `assert_hostname` in your program like:

```
from kubernetes.client import configuration 
config.load_kube_config()                                                 
configuration.assert_hostname = False
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: `configuration.assert_hostname = False` work for me.

Comment: how to specify the container in the pod ?

Comment: Just add `container='name'` to the call

Comment: we should need to add container='containername'
```resp = stream(api_instance.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec, "nginx-deployment-76bf4969df-467z2", 'default',
              command=exec_command,
              container='containername'
              stderr=True, stdin=False,
              stdout=True, tty=False)```

Comment: This answer is life savior. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Watch out when using the stream() suggestion from [Prafull Ladha answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54051435/17454091). It has a lot of pitfalls:

- Will not throw exception in case the command fails. Just return empty string. To cover that, one need to set stream(..., _preload_content=False) and then manually check resp.returncode and manually call resp.readline_stdout in a loop.
- Will timeout if the command takes more than 5min to run without producing any output. To solve that you need to call resp.sock.ping() in a parallel thread.

I'm afraid i don't have a better alternative solution, and not the reputation to add this as comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32089102)

Answer (score 1):

Adding container='name' to the call would work especially if you have any sidecar container like istio-proxy is running on the POD.